# Delete a line from a file in qt?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt3

How to delete two consecutive line using an iterator??

I am trying to create a form to save user and password using QT3.3.
But i also want to modify and delete the user name and password.I am able to delete the user name, but i am not able to delete the immediate next line.The code i have been using is:

```
QStringList::Iterator it;
it = qFind(lines.begin(), lines.end(), str);
if(it != lines.end())
{
 lines.erase(it);
}
```

Can any one suggest any way?

Comment: Current Qt is Qt5.4; you should not use the *ancient* Qt3.3 in 2015. And you should better read all the file in memory, then write a new one.... Or consider [Sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) or [gdbm](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdbm/)

Comment: My work is based on RHEL 4 and the OS has qt 3.3 along with it so only i hv been using it.

Comment: Sorry, you can always compile Qt5.4 from its source code and install it. BTW, I am not sure that basing your work on RHEL4 (published in 2005) is sensible in 2015 (ten years later).

Comment: @user3639779 If you're using RHEL4 and Qt3.3 it seems weird that you would post your questions on StackOverflow instead of dialing up your local BBS and posting there.

Answer (score 2):

`QStringList::erase` returns an iterator that references the element that was behind the element you just erased, so:

```
it = lines.erase(it);

// it now references the line after the erased one, so go again to delete that:
if(it != lines.end()) {
  lines.erase(it);
}
```

Also, obligatory: Is there a reason you use Qt 3.3? That's ancient by now.

Comment: i have been trying this but it gives segmentation fault on executing

Comment: My work is based on RHEL 4 and the OS has qt 3.3 along with it so only i hv been using it.

Comment: @user3639779: basing *current* work on something released ten years ago is very probably a *huge* mistake. In what industry are your working?

Comment: But working on embedded systems does not justify using ancient software to leverage your developments.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that the segfault happens later in the program. What does gdb say? If it really crashes right there, the `QStringList` object has been smashed before this, but I have difficulty imagining a way in which it could have been smashed that would "survive" one `erase` but not two.